# How i can append rows in table using Jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting an array object from TagTargets action method to View using ajax call.This method is returning name,value,min,max.I want to append each value in a new table row. I am using for loop for this purpose but nothing is appending in the table.What thing I am doing wrong.
Thanks

```
   function TargetsData() {
    $("#Tag_Targets_div").show();
    var realTags = $('#Raw_Tag_List').val();
    var calculatedTags = $('#Calculated_Tag_List').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"@Url.Action("TagTargets","CalculatedTags")",
        type: 'Post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'RealTags': realTags, 'CalculatedTags': calculatedTags }),

        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            if (data != null) {
                for (var i; i <= data.length; i++)
                {
                     $('#tagTargets tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>'+data[i] +'</td></tr>');
                 }
                }
                else {
                    alert('Not ok');
                }
            }

    });
    }

 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult TagTargets(List<string> RealTags, List<string> CalculatedTags) 
        {
            List<TagTargetsVM> TagTargetsVMs = new List<TagTargetsVM>();
            foreach (var item in RealTags)
            {
                int IdRealTag = Convert.ToInt32(item);
                TagTargetsVM realObj = db.Raw_Tag_Targets.Where(x => x.Real_Tag_Id_FK == IdRealTag).Select(x => new TagTargetsVM
                {

                    TagName=db.Real_Raw_Points.Where(y=>y.Real_Tag_Id== IdRealTag).Select(z=>z.R_Tag_Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Target_Value=x.Target_Value,
                    Minimum_Target=x.Target_Min_Value,
                    Maximum_Target=x.Target_Max_Value
                }).FirstOrDefault();

                TagTargetsVMs.Add(realObj);
            }
            foreach (var item in CalculatedTags)
            {
                int IdCalculatedTag = Convert.ToInt32(item);

                TagTargetsVM CalculatedObj = db.Calculated_Tag_Targets.Where(x => x.C_Tag_Id_FK == IdCalculatedTag).Select(x => new TagTargetsVM
                {
                    TagName = db.Calculated_Tags.Where(y => y.C_Tag_Id == IdCalculatedTag).Select(z => z.C_Tag_Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Target_Value=x.Target_Value,
                    Maximum_Target=x.Maximum_Target,
                    Minimum_Target=x.Minimum_Target
                }).FirstOrDefault();

                TagTargetsVMs.Add(CalculatedObj);
            }
            return Json(TagTargetsVMs.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

//Html Code
<table id="tagTargets">
            <thead>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
 </table>
```

[image]

Comment: You tagged C#. Do you have C# code related to this issue you need to show? Otherwise, you should remove that tag.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  Appending rows (regardless of ajax) or the ajax call not giving you back what you want/expect?  They're 2 very different and unrelated issues.    Do you get to the `success:` callback?  What's the result of `success: function (data) { console.log(data); ` ?  What about `console.log($('#tagTargets tbody').length)` ?

Comment: Hi freedomn i am getting the success cal and as well data I just want to append it in table as rows.

Comment: FYI, if you use `@` in front of someone's name, they get a notification.  Person asking the question always gets notifications without the @.

Comment: `$('#Raw_Tag_List').val()` / `List<string> RealTags` - look at exactly what you're sending.   `$('#Raw_Tag_List').val()` will only give you a single string value, not a list, so would match with `string RealTags`

Comment: "*I want to append it in table as rows*" - ok, so remove all the other code and just have `$('#tagTargets tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>test</td></tr>")` - does that work?  If that works then there's a mis-match in your `data` - can you provide an example output?  the json string directly from the action preferably, but also an output of `console.log(data)` would suffice.

Comment: @freedomn-m I updated the question and add a picture of formate in which I am getting the data.

Comment: Well your data looks ok and, assuming that's from the success callback, your jquery request and mvc action appear to be ok - so must be to do with `$('#tagTargets tbody').append` - can you include the HTML for that as well?  Also include the output of `console.log($('#tagTargets tbody').length, data.length)` (inside the success).  The next step is to try to reproduce the issue - you've confirmed the ajax request/action/success are working, so you can eliminate these and create a `var data=[]` containing your data and then get that working with your append.

Comment: Did you try: `$('#tagTargets tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>'+data[i].TagName +'</td></tr>');`

Comment: @freedomn-m i added the table code as well but $('#tagTargets tbody').append('<tr class="child"><td>test</td></tr>")   is not working as well

Comment: Good, so you've narrowed it down to only the append code (confirmed) - all the other code is superfluous to the question.  What do you get with `console.log($('[id=tagTargets]').length)` - should be a single number.